# How do I make the google material icon height the same as the text?

Tags: html, css

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAEMA.jpg)

I want to google the material icon the height is the same as the text in the html css.

```
<p><i class="material-symbols-outlined" style="font-size: 13.5px;">login</i> Login</p> 
<p><span class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px;">home</span></p><div class="a"><span class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px;">home</span> Home</div>
```

I don't know how fix this

Comment: Depends. Is there padding around the icon? If not, just stick a display flex on the parent container and `align-items:center`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#txt1{
 font-size:15px;
 line-height:24px;
}
.material-icons{
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<i class="material-icons">login</i><span id="txt1">Login</span>
```